# sequences relating to cauchy and monotone.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

trying to come up with different examples on different situations I mean for example:

1. monotone sequence that is not convergent.
2. a convergent sequence that is not monotone.
3. a set that has no cluster points. (can I say Z?)
4. a bounded sequence that is not convergent. (can I say $(-1)^n$?)
5. a monotone sequence that is not cauchy.

help please!

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$
2. Take $\dfrac{(-1)^n}n$
3. You are right here.
4. Again, you are right here.
5. Again, take the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: what about isolated points? can I again have Z as an example? thank you so much.

Comment: Yes. Every point of $\mathbb Z$ is an isolated point of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: thank you for your time.

Comment: I have a question, did you choose the sequence 1,2,3, ... as an example for 5 because its unbounded (i.e not convergent) so its not cauchy?